# Where is the TextFX option?

Tags: notepad++, plugins

I have Notepad++ 5.9 installed. The **TextFX** option (between Run and Plugins) in the menu is visible.

How can I actually get the TextFX plugin?

Answer (score 12):

The plugin is not installed by default, you need to install it.

1. Go to **Plugins** → **Plugin Manager** → **Show Plugin Manager**.
2. Check **TextFX Characters** and click **Install**.

   [image]
3. Confirm the restart.

   [image]
4. You'll now have the **TextFX** menu.

   [image]

Comment: Notepad++ v6.5.2 added sort lines options to the Edit, Edit lines menu.

Comment: When I try to install TextFx Characters 0.2.6 for Notepad++ v7.3.2 (32-bit) through Plugin Manager, I get an `Installation of TextFx Characters failed.` error. Is this plugin not compatible with v7+?

Comment: My Plugins menu has no Plugin Manager entry which was fixed via https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/2430#issuecomment-343648788

Comment: I have Notepad++ v7.5.5 (64 bit) installed and added the Plugin Manager there as DaveInCaz explained. But there does not seem to be a TextFX plugin. What can I do to get it?

Comment: Does not work, the tab >TextFX does not show up.

Comment: For those who are not able to find the textfx plugin from the menu bar > Plugins > Plugin Manager, do note that textfx plugin is not available for notepad++ 64 bit. See 2019 link :https://sourceforge.net/p/npp-plugins/discussion/667712/thread/4b4f04114f/?limit=25  or https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/17336/code-formatter-notepad-64 for reference. Workarounds include using 32-bit notepad++ or installing it manually (not using plugin manager which has some bugs reported on forum).